# How to make a slack dialog with more than 5 inputs ? Node Slack API

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm currently handling with a problem. I need to make like a form to create something like this:

[image: It is like a format text]

So, I'm trying to make a form with a Slack's Dialog but my problem is that only supports 5 inputs, this is my current process:

[image]

Is there another way to input text or dropdowns and return that kind of format ? or how can I add more inputs (5+) to a dialog ?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you can not have more than 5 inputs in your [Slack Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs). Its the current upper hard limit.
2. Dialogs are the best way on Slack for structured text input. But you could also use text input from a slash command, e.g. `/command "first input" "second input"`
3. You can also create drop downs with [message menus](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-menus)

To solve your problem of needing to query more than 5 inputs from the user in Slack I think you have two options:

- A. Use multiple Dialogs, e.g. you appear to have 9 field, so you
  could first open a Dialog for the first 5 elements and then for the
  last 4 elements.
- B. You mix Dialogs (for text input) with message menus for drop down
  input and/or a slash command, e.g. use a Dialog for the text input and main options. Then show the result as Slack message and allow the user to change the remaining options wit message menu.

**Update July 2017**

You can now use up to 10 elements per Dialog. See [here](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#recent_changes) for details.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I'm going to check how to implement the first option and try to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently the limit is 10 for each dialog. In case you need to retain the state of the previous dialog, or want to get the previous dialog input values in the next dialog submit processors, you can use state field in the dialog attachment. The state field take values as text and you can possibly put a delimiter like below:

"state": "input1|input2|inout3...|input10"

and get the values in the next dialog processor.